# Neo4j 3.3.3 Import CSV Nodes and Relationships using neo4j-admin collisions and taking too much time

Tags: neo4j

Hi i am trying to import some data from csv to neo4j (3.3.3) db and i am using neo4j-admin command to do it and its taking forever to finish. Its running for more than 12 hours straight and still doing same. Am i using the command wrong or there is problem with my data or there is some other issue?

**Process starts fine**

[image: Importing Nodes and relations using neo4j-admin command]

**But after a while it just keeps resolving collisions and keeps doing that for hours**

[image: Resolving collisions takes forever]

Comment: If the process starts and then hangs for hours, maybe it's a memory related problem (too much RAM used). 
You could change default memory setup for the JVM behind Neo4j but, before this, forgive me for this "stupid" question: have you tried importing the CSV only one by one? (separate commands)

Comment: Please show us a sample of the CSV and the query for the load.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it was happening because there were alot duplicate ID’s in node csv files. Removing them fixed the problem.